# Is UTC month ever 'wrong' relative to LocalTime in C# DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime, utc

This is a bit of a 'silly' simple question but I haven't been able to find anything on google (or find the right search term). Nor am I certain as to how to test the question.

Given a `DateTime current = DateTime.Utc;` is there ever a scenario where `DateTime.UtcNow.Month != DateTime.Now.Month`?

Or expressed differently do I need to do this `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(o.CreatedAt.Value.UtcDateTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local).Month == i` or can I simply do `o.CreatedAt.Value.UtcDateTime.Month == i` where i is the Local DateTime Month represented as an integer?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, what do you mean by "Given a `DateTime current = DateTime.Utc;` ? If all you're asking is if UtcNow can ever have a different month value than Now, then yes, if UtcNow != Now, and there is a month crossover there will be a brief period where they're different, every month. For instance, for me, .Now is 15:13, and UtcNow is 13:13, this means there is 2 hour difference. For 2 hours, after midnight to the first every month, UtcNow will still be in the previous month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitively there could be a moment where UTC is in a month and your local time is in a different one. This could happen the last/first day of the month because of the time offset.

For instance. I'm on GMT-3 so at 11:00pm of June 30 I'll be in June but in UTC will be already July 1st.

Comment: Yeah of course, total brainfart. For some reason I totally disconnected that the difference between the time will offset to a different month at the end of the month. I only considered the end of a single day. Thanks for the quick answer